Updating Excel Cell Values With a Timer Fails
I  can't resolve a (probably very simple) problem when trying to recalculate cell values every few seconds by calling Worksheet_Change:
This workbook:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Module1.StartTimer
End Sub

Module1
Dim TimerActive As Boolean
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Sub StartTimer()
    Start_Timer
End Sub
Private Sub Start_Timer()
    TimerActive = True
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Timer"
End Sub
Private Sub Stop_Timer()
    TimerActive = False
End Sub
Private Sub Timer()
    If TimerActive Then
        Sheet1.UpdateTimers
    End If
End Sub

Sheet1
Private Sub UpdateTimers()
    Worksheet_Change Range("CountdownTimers")
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set rng = Range("CountdownTimers")
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
                cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value - Now()
                cell.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            Else
                cell.Value = ""
            End If
        Next cell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Produces error "Method or data member not found" at
'Private Sub Timer()
'If TimerActive Then
'Sheet1.UpdateTimers

Updatetimers should not be Private

I knew it was something simple and obvious. Thanks.
